# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in PDO using PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo, prepare

I ma using PHP's to communicate with an Oracle 11g Database. This code is intended for a user to upload an .xls or .csv file. If .xls, then convert to .csv. If .csv, continue. Afterward, it takes the csv and updates an oracle database. In the past, I have used sql injection without realizing the security disadvantages associated with it. So, I began to learn to use PDO. However, I am very new. The code I have designed (below) gets this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /opt/apache/servers/planninganddesign/htdocs/JointUse/update_handler.php on line 89
```

Line 89 is marked, below.

Code:

```
<?php
require_once('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'); 
require_once("mcl_Oci.php");
?>

<br>

<?php

    $filename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
    $file = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($ext='xls') {



        $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
        $inputFileName = $file;

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

        $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

        foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
                $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
                $objWriter->save('abc.csv');}
        $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r'); 
            if($files) {
                    while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                    $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
            }           echo 'Your .xls file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';
        }
        elseif ($ext='csv'){
            while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                    $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
            }   echo 'Your .csv file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';
        }
        else {
            echo "This is not an accepted file type. Please save as either '*.csv' or '*.xls' and re-upload.";
        }
    }


    $ArrayNumber = 0;   

    while ($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"] != NULL) {

    $ArrayNumber = $ArrayNumber + 1;
    $RECEIVED=$csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["1"];
    $REGION=$csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["2"];
    $PERMIT=$csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["3"];
    $CUSTOMER=$csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["4"];
    $TO_BUSINESS=$csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["5"];
    $TO_PERMIT=$csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["6"];
    $POWER_ADDRESS=$csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["7"];
    $COMPANY=$csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["8"];
    $MAP_SECTION = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["9"];
    $POLES = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["10"];
    $FEE = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["11"];
    $INVOICE = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["12"];
    $DATE_LARRY = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["13"];
    $DAYS_LARRY = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["14"];
    $PI_PON = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["15"];
    $DATE_PD = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["16"];
    $DATE_LARRY_PD = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["17"];
    $RETURNED = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["18"];
    $DAYS_PD = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["19"];
    $ERRORS_PD = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["20"];
    $ERRORS_MULTIPLE = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["21"];
    $DATE_MAKEREADY_JU = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["22"];
    $DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["23"];
    $DAYS_MAKEREADY = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["24"];
    $DAYS_JU_PROCES = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["25"];
    $APPROVAL = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["26"];
    $DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["27"];
    $DATE_PLANNING = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["28"];
    $DAYS_OPEN = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["29"];
    $DATE_ROUTED = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["30"];
    $DAYS_TOTAL = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["31"];
    $COMMENTS = $csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["32"];

    $conn = oci_connect("user", "pass", "(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=host)(port=1533))(connect_data=(service_name=name)))");
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO INTOXDM.JOINT_USE (RECEIVED, REGION, PERMIT, CUSTOMER, TO_BUSINESS, TO_PERMIT, POWER_ADDRESS, COMPANY, MAPSECTION, POLES, FEE, INVOICE, DATE_LARRY, DAYS_LARRY, PI_PON, DATE_PD, DAYS_LARRY_PD, RETURNED, DAYS_PD, ERRORS_PD, ERRORS_MULTIPLE, DATE_MAKEREADY_JU, DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE, DAYS_MAKEREADY, DAYS_JU_PROCES, APPROVAL, DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU, DATE_PLANNING, DAYS_OPEN, DATE_ROUTED, DAYS_TOTAL, COMMENTS)
         VALUES (:RECEIVED, :REGION, :PERMIT, :CUSTOMER, :TO_BUSIENSS, :TO_PERMIT, :POWER_ADDRESS, :COMPANY, :MAP_SECTION, :POLES, :FEE, :INVOICE, :DATE_LARRY, :DAYS_LARRY, :PI_PON, :DATE_PD, :DATE_LARRY_PD, :RETURNED, :DAYS_PD, :ERRORS_PD, :ERRORS_MULTIPLE, 
        :DATE_MAKEREADY_JU, :DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE, :DAYS_MAKEREADY, :DAYS_JU_PROCES, :APPROVAL, :DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU, :DATE_PLANNING, :DAYS_OPEN, :DATE_ROUTED, :DAYS_TOTAL, :COMMENTS)';
    *****$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);***** line 89
    $sql->bindValue(':RECEIVED',$RECEIVED);
    $sql->bindValue('REGION',$REGION);
    $sql->bindValue(':PERMIT',$PERMIT);
    $sql->bindValue(':TO_BUSINESS',$TO_BUSINESS);
    $sql->bindValue(':TO_PERMIT',$TO_PERMIT);
    $sql->bindValue(':POWER_ADDRESS',$POWER_ADDRESS);
    $sql->bindValue(':MAP_SECTION',$MAP_SECTION);
    $sql->bindValue(':POLES',$POLES);
    $sql->bindValue(':FEE',$FEE);
    $sql->bindValue(':INVOICE',$INVOCE);
    $sql->bindValue(':$DATE_LARRY',$DATE_LARRY);
    $sql->bindValue(':$DAYS_LARRY',$DAYS_LARRY);
    $sql->bindValue(':$PI_PON',$PI_PON);
    $sql->bindValue(':$DATE_PD',$DATE_PD);
    $sql->bindValue(':$DATE_LARRY_PD',$DATE_LARRY_PD);
    $sql->bindValue(':RETURNED',$RETURNED);
    $sql->bindValue(':DAYS_PD',$DAYS_PD);
    $sql->bindValue(':ERRORS_PD',$ERRORS_PD);
    $sql->bindValue(':ERRORS_MULTIPLE',$ERRORS_MULTIPLE);
    $sql->bindValue(':DATE_MAKEREADY_JU',$DATE_MAKEREADY_JU);
    $sql->bindValue(':DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE',$DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE);
    $sql->bindValue(':DAYS_MAKEREADY',$DAYS_MAKEREADY);
    $sql->bindValue(':DAYS_JU_PROCES',$DAYS_JU_PROCES);
    $sql->bindValue(':DATE_PERMIT_IN_JU',$DATE_PERMIT_IN_JU);
    $sql->bindValue(':DATE_PLANNING',$DATE_PLANNING);
    $sql->bindValue(':DAYS_OPEN',$DAYS_OPEN);
    $sql->bindValue(':DATE_ROUTED',$DATE_ROUTED);
    $sql->bindValue(':DAYS_TOTAL',$DAYS_TOTAL);
    $sql->bindValue(':COMMENTS',$COMMENTS);
    $stmt->execute();

    $exec = execute();

    }
?>
```

What could cause this issue, and is there an easy way around it? TIA!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983). You cannot mix the `oci_` functions with the `PDO` functions. Either use 100% `oci` or 100% PDO (by using [`PDO_OCI`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php)).

Comment: To my eye it looks like the call to `oci_connect` failed and `$conn` doesn't refer to a valid connection. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks for the help, but the connection definitely succeeds. I have other pages using the exact same conn string pulling data from the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oci extension does not have an object-oriented usage. `oci_connect()` returns a *resource*, not an object. Resources don't have methods.

The comment from @h2ooooooo is correct. You seem to be mixing oci usage and PDO usage. Pick one or the other, preferably PDO.

In other words, instead of calling `oci_connect()`, do this:

```
$dsn = 'oci:dbname=host:1533/name';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

If that succeeds, you should be able to use `$conn` as a PDO object.

But there are a couple of other mistakes in your code.

```
$sql->bindValue(':RECEIVED',$RECEIVED);
```

If you use `bindValue()`, it's a method of your statement object, not the `$sql` string. Strings don't have methods. Do this instead:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':RECEIVED',$RECEIVED);
```

And likewise for all the other calls to `bindValue()`.

You also have a superfluous line that appears to do nothing at the end of your code:

```
$exec = execute();
```

Unless you have a function `execute()` in your application, I don't know what this is supposed to do.

Another mistake: your `while` loop tests if the current index `$ArrayNumber` has an entry, then you increment `$ArrayNumber` before you get the values. You are kind of guaranteed to cause an error, because your code will try to read past the end of the array. You should increment `$ArrayNumber` *after* you read the data in that array element.

Or else use a `for` loop instead of `while`:

```
$count = count($csv_array);
for ($ArrayNumber = 0; $ArrayNumber < $count; ++$ArrayNumber) {
  ...
```

Or even simpler:

```
foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
  ...
```

Some tips about using prepared statements. You can skip all the tedious `bindValue()` calls if you just pass an array to `PDOStatement::execute()`. And you already have your data in an array! You don't even need to create all those local variables.

Since your data is indexed with integers instead of column names, you should use ordinal parameters (with `?` as the placeholder) instead of named parameters.

Also, you don't need to prepare the statement for every iteration of the loop. One of the best advantages of prepared statements is that you can prepare it once and re-use it during a loop, with different values.

Here's an example:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO INTOXDM.JOINT_USE (RECEIVED, REGION, PERMIT, CUSTOMER, TO_BUSINESS, TO_PERMIT, POWER_ADDRESS, COMPANY, MAPSECTION, POLES, FEE, INVOICE, DATE_LARRY, DAYS_LARRY, PI_PON, DATE_PD, DAYS_LARRY_PD, RETURNED, DAYS_PD, ERRORS_PD, ERRORS_MULTIPLE, DATE_MAKEREADY_JU, DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE, DAYS_MAKEREADY, DAYS_JU_PROCES, APPROVAL, DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU, DATE_PLANNING, DAYS_OPEN, DATE_ROUTED, DAYS_TOTAL, COMMENTS)
     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
  $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

One final tip: you do this after the data has been read:

```
echo 'Your .csv file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';
```

But I would output that message after the data has successfully imported into the database. The positive message may not turn out to be true if there is any problem inserting into the database.

Comment: First off, thank you with the detailed answer which taught me quite a bit. I appreciate it! When I update my connection string i get the following: `Connection failed: could not find driver`. The same error from before also appears, however I imagine this may be due to the error posted above. Does this just mean I need to install PDO? How can I do this?

Comment: Your PHP instance seems not to have the OCI driver installed. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pdo+oci+could+not+find+driver for answers to that issue.